# How can I initilize a variable of a type which is wrapped around another type?

Tags: c++, types

I can do this

```
class Draw
{
public:
    Draw();

    static const Shape_f32 shape;

}
```

But what if I want to initilize the inner types of shape to a certain value? Like

```
shape.side.value = 5.0;
```

I tried to do these different solutions:

1.

```
class Draw
{
public:
    Draw();

    static const Shape_f32 shape.shape.value = 5.0;

}
```

2. 

```
class Draw
{
public:
    Draw() {
            shape.side.value = 5.0;
    };

    static const Shape_f32 shape;

}
```

I am not able to make any modifications to the type `Shape_f32` here. So is what i want to do possible? It seems like I somehow need to create a type initializer that accepts a value.

Definition of Shape_f32

```
typedef struct Shape_f32_
{
    PI_side side;
} Shape_f32;

typedef struct PI_side_
{
    float value;
} PI_side;
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `Shape_f32`. Do you know how to _define_ a static class member?

Comment: @KamilCuk added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list initialisation:

```
inline static const Shape_f32 shape {
    .side {
        .value = 5.0,
    },
};
```

Prior to C++20 however, you cannot use designated initialisers, and you need to initialise the members in order of their declaration instead.

P.S. If you define the static variable in a header, you should declare it inline in case you odr-use it.

Comment: Yea this is prior to C++20, I am not sure how to initialize in order of declaration.

Comment: @FelixRosén Simply remove the variable names from the example, and the dot prefix, and the equals symbol. And add initialisers for any members that precede the ones that you want to have specific values.

Comment: Yea, so i simply did: `static const Shape_f32 shape {{5.0}}`

Answer (score 0):

For you case, simple initializer list outside class definition should be sufficient (if you know all of the fields inside Shape_f32)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef struct PI_side_
{
    float value;
} PI_side;

typedef struct Shape_f32_
{
    PI_side side;
} Shape_f32;

struct Foo{
  public:
    float get() {return bar_.side.value;}

  private:
    static const Shape_f32 bar_;
};

// definition outside the class, it would be best if this line is inside .cpp where you are using "Foo"
const Shape_f32 Foo::bar_ = {5};

int main() {
  Foo var;
  std::cout << var.get() << std::endl;
}
```

This normally outputs `5`

edit: it also works for private/protected members